# Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'draggable'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I keep get this error:

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'draggable'

I have included all necessary script for this code to work. 
What I'm doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <style>
        #test {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 0.5em;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#test").draggable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="test" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure the jquery ui file path is correct

Comment: Yes, the path is correct

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n4uv665pzkums4f/Screenshot%202014-06-10%2012.49.59.png

Comment: Change the jquery and jquery ui paths for CDN hosted version just to test - it could be your UI file doesn't have the draggable part to it

Comment: I check the jquery ui for draggable function. The function is included in the file.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/khrf40ebdfp1y7z/Screenshot%202014-06-10%2012.58.04.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the id "`#draggable`"  to "`#test`" in internal style sheet. Beacause draggable id is not present in your html.

```
#test   {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 0.5em;
        }
```

Comment: Changed from #draggable to #test. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="test" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
   </div>
</div>
```